# C# Console Application No Dependency or Reference

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-project

I am trying to create a C# console application that has a depedency or reference to my class libary BUT everytime I create a console application Visual Studio Mac does not give me a depedency option or an option to add my class libary as a reference.

I've added some screenshots bellow so you can take a look. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUDwx.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovy14.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi8mf.png)

Comment: Try right clicking on the second Homework2, not the top one. The top is the solution, you can't add references to a solution, the second one is the project. You can have multiple projects per solution, each with their own references, so you right click the project not the solution.